# Mimic Stack Allocation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, v8

I currently write a JS wrapper for a C API which runs in node.js. The original API has hundreds of different structs.

The original API style looks like this:

```
MYAPI a = {};
a.prop = 2;
...
```

The JS version looks like this:

```
let a = new MYAPI();
a.prop = 2;
```

The above JS example becomes costly when its placed in a loop - my C++ wrapper code for each struct is quite expensive, some structs have ~50 members. But what if it would be possible to re-use a class or do a stack allocation?

I thought of something like this:

```
let a = MYAPI();
a.prop = 2;
```

In the C++ wrapper code, i can then detect when a class gets called without the 'new' keyword. When there is no constructor call, use a cached version (always the same for this specific code location).

The problem here is that, to do a "stack allocation", a user has to pass a unique id into the class call, e.g.:

```
let a = MYAPI(3);
```

Having the user determine a unique id each time is not acceptable

In my opinion, the best way would be e.g.:

```
let a = MYAPI(_STACK_OFFSET_);
// _STACK_OFFSET_ returns a unique number for this specific source code location, never changes
```

or just:

```
let a = MYAPI(); // always the same object at this source code location
```

Another solution is to create and cache all necessary classes at global level and then use them in the actual code - but in my experience this quickly becomes a mess.

```
let $0 = new MYAPI();

(function updateLoop() {
  setTimeout(updateLoop, 0);
  let a = $0;
  a.prop = 2;
})();
```

What I want to achieve:

```
function test() {
  let a = MYAPI();
  console.log(a.id); // id is always 0
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    let b = MYAPI();
    console.log(b.id); // is always 1
  };
};

test(); // logs: 0, 1, 1, 1, 1...
test(); // logs: 0, 1, 1, 1, 1...
```

I spent many days looking for a solution, I couldn't find any other than throwing an Error and then getting the unique id out of the stack trace line/column number - which in performance terms is not acceptable.

Other things I checked, but which I can't use / are too messy:

- v8::Object's GetIdentityHash, but the user still has to do caching and a unique hash is not guaranteed
- Using a custom JS transpiler which replaces all `_STACK_OFFSET_` with a unique number generated by the given code location at parse-time

I know that JS shouldn't be used as/like C, but I think this could be a handy solution to lower GC pressure and shorten some code paths - or at least it's an interesting experiment.

Comment: To be honest, I am still a bit confused by the end goal. I get bits of the idea but I can't see the general picture. Looking at the example of what you want to achieve leads me to suspect you may have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but I can't really say. Still, if you really do only want unique IDs for calling your API, then what about passing in the current timestamp in milliseconds? I doubt that would have duplicates.

Comment: I'm not clear on your problem either. In the 'what do I want to achieve', how is the MYAPI call supposed to determine whether to increase the 'id' value or not? If you simply want to re-use the value, just move the let b = MYAPI(); call outside of the loop.

Comment: @TinkerTank The 'id' should be unique and never change. I'm asking how to get such an id without having the user to manually enter it. One (bad) way to get this 'id' is to generate it by the source code location by throwing an Error (and extracting it from the stack trace), which is then unique and independent of the program execution. I have hundreds of classes which get used in heavy loops - having such a cache mechanism could help performance. Unique id's would then allow to return a cached, pre-instantiated and unique class per code location, instead of creating a new one each time

Comment: Allright, I finally get what you mean: You'd like an id that's dependent on the *exact code-line* that the function was called. However, I would strongly recommend against that solution. Even though it's not entirely impossible (like you said, there's ways of getting line-numbers), it's so far outside of how any other programmer would expect a function to react, that it will make your code incredibly hard to read. Not to mention performance, or problems if the .js file gets minified, and all code ends up on a single line..

Comment: Thank's for pointing this out, though I'm still curious how this could be implemented

Comment: My suggestion would be to take a step back and think about how you could redesign the API to avoid unnecessary slow operations. For example, maybe having individual function calls taking simple arguments works better than creating heavyweight structs? Maybe you can make the struct creation lightweight and move expensive operations into functions that are only called when necessary (i.e. when there is no way to optimize them away anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

What I'm getting is that you want to have a unique value for a variable, every time a javascript function is called.

To be honest, I don't understand at all what you're doing with the c-wrapper, or what you mean with a 'stack allocation' in this case, or whether that's really the best way to solve your performance problem, but I'm assuming it doesn't matter.

You could use the following js:

```
function MyApiWrapper() {
    if (MyApiWrapper.counter === undefined) {
        MyApiWrapper.counter = 0;
    }
    MyApiWrapper.counter++;
    return MYAPI(MyApiWrapper.counter);
}
```

Use as following:

```
let a = MyApiWrapper();
```

The MyApiWrapper.counter var will increase monotonically for every time the MyApiWrapper() function is called. The function will return the results of a MYAPI(number) call, where the number will be different (increased by one) every time it's called.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I updated the main post including a hopefully better example what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to make any caching dependent on the exact code-line it was called from. Instead, does this solution help you?

```
function generateCacheId() {
    if (generateCacheId.nextCacheId === undefined) {
        generateCacheId.nextCacheId = -1;
    }
    generateCacheId.nextCacheId++;
    return MYAPI(generateCacheId.nextCacheId);
}
```

Use as following:

```
function test() {
  let cacheIdA = generateCacheId();
  let a = MYAPI(cacheIdA);
  console.log(a.id); // id is always 0

  let cacheIdB = generateCacheId();
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    let b = MYAPI(cacheIdB);
    console.log(b.id); // is always 1
  };
};

test(); // logs: 0, 1, 1, 1, 1...
test(); // logs: 0, 1, 1, 1, 1...
```

In this way, you do make it very clear in your code when you want to use a cached object, and where not. It can be made in such a way that each code-line where MYAPI is called gets its own cache, without relying on line-numbers.